# C++ puttting one element of vector to another vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, copy, sdl

I am working on a RTS game using SDL. I have a woodyard class whose object will collect wood from nearby trees. In the class I create a vector called temp_trees and as an argument for the constructor I use a vector of tree objects that I pass in.

The woodyard constructor:

```
woodyard::woodyard(int x, int y, int HP, int id, vector<Tree> trees)
{
...
vector<Tree> temp_trees;
for(int i = 0; i < trees.size(); i++)
{
    if((trees[i].xPos - 100) / 50 >= x - 5 && (trees[i].xPos - 100) / 50 <= x + 4)
    {
        if((trees[i].yPos - 100) / 50 >= y - 5 && (trees[i].yPos - 100) / 50 <= y + 4)
        {
            temp_trees.push_back(trees[i]);
        }
    }
}

collect_control = 0;
no = 0;
}
```

the collect_wood function:

```
void woodyard::collect_wood(){
if(no == 5)
{
 temp_trees[collect_control].drewno -= 1;
 if(temp_trees[collect_control].drewno <= 0){
 collect_control++;
 temp_trees.erase(temp_trees.begin());
}}


no++;
if(no >= 10){
  no = 0;
}}
```

The program crashes just after start.
Can anybody see any errors in this code??

PS: I suppose that there might be something wrong with copping elements from one vector to another in the constructor.

Comment: Did you run it through the debugger? Where did the debugger stop? What error did it give you?

Comment: it stopped at"temp_trees[collect_control].drewno -= 1;"

Comment: where is `temp_trees` declared, WRT the `collect_wood` method?

Comment: temp_tree is in the constructor of woodyard class(it's in the post) collect wood is declared in the header file of woodyard

Comment: When it stops at that line: a) what is the value of collect_control and b) what is the size of temp_trees?

Comment: temp_trees's size is 0 and value of control is also 0

Answer (score 0):

The constructor doesn't contain any illegal operation.

And collect_wood(), although unintelligible, doesn't contain any obvious reason for making it crash.

Which is the value of `collect_control`? Do you check if it is `< temp_trees.size()`? Being aware that `temp_trees.size()` keep changing since you are erasing elements.

Probably `collect_control` shouldn't be incremented after the erase: all elements shift back, and collect_control after the erase is already pointing to the next element.

Note: Consider that `temp_trees.erase(temp_trees.begin());` is one of the most inefficient things you could do with a vector (deleting the first element).

Comment: The reason for which I am not checking the size of temp_trees IS the fact that it is changing. The collect_control value decides of the order in which Tree objects are used. It is set to 0 at start and increments each time the current Tree object gets used up and destroyed. This makes the function start with the FIRST Tree in the vector and deletes the FIRST Tree when the time comes

Comment: @user2466076 In which way would it harm checking if collect_control < temp_trees.size() *before* statements like temp_trees[collect_control], at least while you are debugging?

Answer (score 0):

In the woodyard constructor, you are declaring a temporary, function-scoped variable "temp_trees".

```
woodyard::woodyard(int x, int y, int HP, int id, vector<Tree> trees)
{
...
vector<Tree> temp_trees;
```

If you have a vector member called temp_trees, this declaration is hiding it. So your member function is NOT seeing the same vector:

```
void woodyard::collect_wood(){
if(no == 5)
{
 temp_trees[collect_control].drewno -= 1;
```

Also, without seeing the rest of the code, I wouldn't know how you are ensuring that there are at least "collect_control" members in the vector.

```
#include <assert.h>
...
assert(collect_control < temp_trees.size());
```

or if you're using visual studio you can do

```
if(collect_control >= temp_trees.size())
    DebugBreak();
```

"size()" is a 1-based value but array index operators are zero based. That means, when there is one entry in the vector, it will be vector[0]. If the vector is empty, vector[0] is illegal - it does not exist. And emptiness is denoted by size being 0. size must *always* be greater than the element index you are trying to access.

Comment: my mistake the temp_trees vector is declared in the header

Comment: then the problem is that it is empty. size() == 0 means empty, so you cannot access temp_trees[0] because there ARE no elements. (see last paragraph of edited answer)

Comment: before the `temp_trees[...].drewno = -1`. it will fire because you are trying to access the first element of no elements.

Comment: Given the code you've shown, the problem is either that you have a private "temp_trees" in the constructor or else the problem is that you are not adding any trees to your vector.

Comment: the only place I use .size() is for the trees which is an exterior value so there should be no problem(There will be always some elements)

Comment: This is either because (a) you have TWO vectors called "temp_trees" - the one in the header and the one you declare in the constructor, (b) your logic is failing to add any members.

The result is that there are no elements in the vector visible to "collect_wood()". This is why size() is zero. That means "this vector is empty" so it is illegal to use the [] operator with ANY value. temp_tress[0] is not legal because there are no elements.

Comment: @user2466076 Perfect, so you found the error. Try also to print value of temp_trees.empty()

Comment: I moved the temp vector in the .cpp file out of the class elements and it works perfectly\

Comment: See http://ideone.com/5880UM for why this problem occurs. It's called "Shadow Variables". Visual Studio doesn't provide an easy way to detect it as an error but other compilers (e.g gcc with -Wall or -wshadow) do.

Comment: However, now the trees aren't affected

Comment: But thats my problem
and I use Codeblocks not Visual Studio

Comment: Because of the way you are naming things, you are going to run into similar problems (may even be your larger problem). A common best-practice is to use prefixes. See the following example: http://ideone.com/gFcvVe

Comment: Also, I suspect your problem is that your bounding box check is failing because you "- 100" on both sides of the equation. I think you probably want to add 100 on one side of the &&